# dictionary.Exists(key) always False

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am trying to build a validation tool that consists of a header check, a dupe check, and a vLookup. In the **DuplicateCheck** subroutine, I am adding all unique values from a range to a dictionary using .Exists() = False; this check is failing consistantly and I am getting duplicate values added. Similar problems seemed to be fixed using lower() or upper(), but my testing has been with numbers such as "1", "2", "3", or values such as "k1", "k2", "k2".

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wbThis As ThisWorkbook
Dim wsOld, wsNew, wsValid As Worksheet
Dim lColOld, lColNew, lRowOld, lRowNew, iRow, iCol As Long
Dim cellTarget, cellKey As Variant
Dim cellValid, dataOld, dataNew As Range
```

---

```
Sub Execute()

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsOld = wbThis.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsNew = wbThis.Worksheets(2)
    Set wsValid = wbThis.Worksheets(3)

    lColOld = wsOld.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lColNew = wsNew.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lRowOld = wsOld.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lRowNew = wsNew.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set dataOld = wsOld.Range("A1").Resize(lRowOld, lColOld)
    Set dataNew = wsNew.Range("A1").Resize(lRowNew, lColNew)

    Call Validation.HeaderCheck
    Call Validation.DuplicateCheck
    Call Validation.vLookup

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub HeaderCheck()

    Application.StatusBar = "Checking headers..."

    Dim i As Long

    With wsNew
        For i = 1 To lColNew
            If (wsNew.Cells(1, i) <> wsOld.Cells(1, i)) Then
                MsgBox ("Column " & i & " on New Data is not the same as Old Data. This tool will not work with differences in headers. Please reorder your fields and run the tool again.")
                Application.StatusBar = False
                End
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    With wsOld
        For i = 1 To lColOld
            If (wsOld.Cells(1, i) <> wsNew.Cells(1, i)) Then
                MsgBox ("Column " & i & " on Old Data is not the same as New Data. This tool will not work with differences in headers. Please reorder your fields and run the tool again.")
                Application.StatusBar = False
                End
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub DuplicateCheck()

    Dim iterator As Long
    Dim dicKeys As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dicDupes As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim progPercent As Double
    Dim keys As Range
    Dim wsDupes As Worksheet

    Set keys = wsNew.Range("A2").Resize(lRowNew, 1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    iterator = 1
    For Each key In keys
        If dicKeys.Exists(key) = False Then
            dicKeys.Add key, iterator 'HERE IS THE BUG----------------------
        Else
            dicDupes.Add key, iterator
        End If
        progPercent = iterator / keys.Count
        Application.StatusBar = "Identifying duplicates: " & Format(progPercent, "0%")
        iterator = iterator + 1
    Next key


    If (dicDupes.Count <> 0) Then
        Set wsDupes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(, wsValid, 1)
            wsDupes.Name = "Duplicates"
            iterator = 1
            For Each key In dicDupes
                    If (dicDupes(key) <> "") Then
                        wsDupes.Cells(iterator, 1).Value = dicDupes(key)
                    End If
                progPercent = iterator / dicDupes.Count
                Application.StatusBar = "Marking duplicates: " & Format(progPercent, "0%")
                iterator = iterator + 1
            Next key
    End If

    Set dicKeys = Nothing
    Set dicDupes = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub vLookup()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim progPercent As Double

    For iRow = 2 To lRowNew
        Set cellKey = wsNew.Cells(iRow, 1)

        For iCol = 1 To lColNew
            Set cellTarget = wsNew.Cells(iRow, iCol)
            Set cellValid = wsValid.Cells(iRow, iCol)

            On Error GoTo errhandler
            If (IsError(Application.vLookup(cellKey.Value, dataOld, iCol, False)) = False) Then
                If (cellTarget = Application.vLookup(cellKey.Value, dataOld, iCol, False)) Then
                    cellValid.Value = cellTarget
                Else
                    cellValid.Value = "ERROR"
                End If
            Else
                If (cellValid.Column = 1) Then
                    If (cellValid.Column = 1) Then
                        cellValid.Value = cellKey
                        cellValid.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                    End If
                Else
                    cellValid.Value = "ERROR"
                End If
            End If

        Next iCol

        progPercent = (iRow - 1) / (lRowNew - 1)

        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & iRow - 1 & " of " & lRowNew - 1 & ": " & Format(progPercent, "0%")

    Next iRow

    Application.StatusBar = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
errhandler:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
End Sub
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code to go through. Have you read [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Mathieu. I tried to break up the code by subroutine and identified the specific module in the introduction to give some direction, but I did not want to leave out the rest in case something outside of that sub was causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah it's a common misconception about this site - basically, SO isn't a "help me debug my code" service; questions are meant to be searchable and useful for other people too, so if you encounter a specific issue, you make a small piece of code that reproduces that specific issue (an MCVE), and post *that*. That way the answers help you fix your code, and also help anyone else looking up a solution to a similar problem they're having - without a MCVE, it's harder for a reader to say "hmm yeah, that's the problem I'm having!" =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
Dim key As Variant
Dim progPercent As Double
Dim keys As Range
```

Then when you make the check here:

```
For Each key In keys
    If dicKeys.Exists(key) = False Then
        dicKeys.Add key, iterator 'HERE IS THE BUG----------------------
    Else
        dicDupes.Add key, iterator
    End If
Next
```

It compares the `key` as `Range` and not as `value`.
Try something like this:

```
If dicKeys.Exists(key.Value2) = False Then
    dicKeys.Add key.Value2, iterator
```

Or find another way not to work with the object, but with its value.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to propose looking at the value of `key` in each iteration to see what's in there. Might even be some special Variant value, like `Empty`. I think the key here (hehe) is to handle the cell contents which will be turned into keys, as Strings, not Variants.

Comment: @Inarion - if you say `Dim key As String`, then the `For Each key In keys` would not work (a few steps further are needed). But in general it is  a good idea! :)

Comment: @Vityata Yeah, I know. Was trying to keep it short. Sorry for not being clearer! :)

Comment: @Inarion - I know :) Initially I thought of the same, but after seeing the error I thought it would be shorter to explain it this way.